# how to start monit daemon with all processes unmonitored

Tags: ubuntu, monit

it seems that by default starting monit the first time when there is no state file(my state file gets blown away on reboot) will start all processes in monitored mode.  I want to start the daemon in unmonitored mode, then start up each processes individually using "monit start" commands.

i can't seem to find any documentation in monit on how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Ubuntu there is a script that gets run as soon as monit starts if it exists.

```
/etc/monit/monit_delay
```

You can simply add a `monit unmonitor all` to this script.  And all monitoring will get disabled basically as soon as the service starts.

Comment: This works, but I'm trying to understand exactly what monit is doing.  Does monit just run every script in this directory before starting the daemon?  I can't find anything about this in the man page.

Comment: The Debian/Ubuntu startup script runs it.  See `/etc/init.d/monit`.

Comment: Thanks!  I'd upvote, but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: Any idea how to do something similar on CentOS?  I suppose I could manually modify /etc/init.d/monit, if need be.